# How do I create sandbox users?

Tags: paypal, sandbox, paypal-sandbox

All the PayPal documentation states that in order to create sandbox users I log in to  developer.paypal.com using my normal login details.

And then click Applications & Sandbox Accounts

There is No Applications option anywhere on the page!  I see the Paypal interface has been updated recently. Is there new details I am missing?  I have searched everywhere on PayPal help and it all refers to an 'Applications' option on the screen.

Help?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create your account, You will find an menu "Dashboard"
Click on that.

After that in the side menu you will find Sandbox->accounts, here you will find create account button.
For further refernce follow:- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_create-accounts/

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  You are a super star.  I was going mad.  Of course one of the instructions say click on the Dashboard option first. I did click on it a few times but it sometimes appears to do nothing, or is very slow.